# Eclipse jdk 8 and weblogic 12C

Tags: java-8, weblogic12c

we are migrating from JDK 5 to JDK 8 and seeing lot of challenges because of my old technology stack.

The eclipse KEPLER does not support JDK 1.8, so i had to migrate to newer version of eclipse, but latest eclipse does not support Jboss 1.7, so i had to look into other options like weblogic 12( our production application server version), but i feel the world has become hard to me ( working with old stack) to integrate all these.

Following is my requirement.

1. Eclipse to support JDK 1.8 ( Free to use for development)
2. Weblogic 12c to be integrated with eclipse version ( Free to use for development).

Any help or suggestion or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse)
All informations are available in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/oepe12214/oepe/index.html).

Comment: Appreciate your response, i will check the shared link